# Fix jumping of multiple progress bars (tqdm) in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, terminal, multiprocessing, progress-bar, tqdm

I want to parallelize a task (`progresser()`) for a range of input parameters (`L`). The progress of each task should be monitored by an individual progress bar in the terminal. I'm using the `tqdm` package for the progress bars. The following code works on my Mac for up to 23 progress bars (`L = list(range(23))` and below), but produces chaotic jumping of the progress bars starting at `L = list(range(24))`. Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

```py
from time import sleep
import random
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support, RLock

L = list(range(24)) # works until 23, breaks starting at 24

def progresser(n):
    text = f'#{n}'

    sampling_counts = 10
    with tqdm(total=sampling_counts, desc=text, position=n+1) as pbar:
        for i in range(sampling_counts):
            sleep(random.uniform(0, 1))
            pbar.update(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()

    p = Pool(processes=None,
                initargs=(RLock(),), initializer=tqdm.set_lock
                )
    p.map(progresser, L)
    print('\n' * (len(L) + 1))
```

As an example of how it should look like in general, I provide a screenshot for `L = list(range(16))` below.

[image: multiprocessing progess bars]

versions: `python==3.7.3`, `tqdm==4.32.1`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not getting any jumping when I set the size to 30. Maybe you have more processors and can have more workers running.

However, if n grows large you will start to see jumps because of the nature of the chunksize.

I.e 
`p.map` will split your input into chunksizes and give each process a chunk. So as `n` grows larger, so does your chunksize, and so does your ....... yup `position` (pos=n+1)!

Note: Although map preserves the order of the results *returned*. The order its *computed* is arbitrary.

As `n` grows large I would suggest using processor id as the position to view progress on a per process basis.

```
from time import sleep
import random
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support, RLock
from multiprocessing import current_process


def progresser(n):
    text = f'#{n}'
    sampling_counts = 10
    current = current_process()
    pos = current._identity[0]-1

    with tqdm(total=sampling_counts, desc=text, position=pos) as pbar:
        for i in range(sampling_counts):
            sleep(random.uniform(0, 1))
            pbar.update(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    L = list(range(30)) # works until 23, breaks starting at 24
    # p = Pool(processes=None,
    #         initargs=(RLock(),), initializer=tqdm.set_lock
    #         )
    with Pool(initializer=tqdm.set_lock, initargs=(tqdm.get_lock(),)) as p: 
        p.map(progresser, L)
        print('\n' * (len(L) + 1))
```